# Does mongodb automatically create an index on the _id field of embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongodb and mongoose on a node.js project and I was wondering do I have to ensureIndex on the _id fields of embedded items?

That is, I see that mongodb automatically creates an index on _id fields of collections, does it also do the same for _id fields of embedded collections?

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  _id: "someid1",
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  _id: "someid2",
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My instinct was no, so I just tried it:

```
> db.foo.find()

> db.foo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "foo.foo"
    }
]

> db.foo.insert({
...    _id: "joe",
...    name: "Joe Bookreader",
...    addresses: [
...                 {
...                   _id: "someid1",
...                   street: "123 Fake Street",
...                   city: "Faketon",
...                   state: "MA",
...                   zip: "12345"
...                 },
...                 {
...                   _id: "someid2",
...                   street: "1 Some Other Street",
...                   city: "Boston",
...                   state: "MA",
...                   zip: "12345"
...                 }
...               ]
...  })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.foo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "foo.foo"
    }
]
>
```

Looks like no it does not automatically create indexes on subdocuments.

Answer (score 3):

From MongoDB documentation:

```
By default, MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field during the creation of a collection.
```

Comment: source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-_id-index

Answer (score 1):

Yes its does according to documentation mongo dB creates a unique index on _id field.
[Default _id Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-_id-index)